# Boot looping / Corrupted data partition, CWM crashes when restoring to factory defaults

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, clockworkmod-recovery, unbricking

Been using the Alpha version of CM7 for the Samsung T989 (T-Mobile Galaxy S II) for over 2 weeks now. Seems like when I rebooted it today it managed to corrupt the data partition.

Symptoms: 
-Normal starts loop just after the kernel screen.
-CWM boots and works
-ODIN boots.
-CWM crashes when doing factory reset or restoring the data partition of a backup or formatting the data partition

This happened to me 2 days after installing CM7, the same version I'm still using. I was similarly stuck, but then I tried restoring my nandroid backup and eventually I could re-apply the CM7 zip and the phone started fine to a blank android.

Is there a way to solve this issue with my partitions? I am not too comfortable with re-partitioning it because I'm aware this can damage the boot sectors and brick it quickly if I don't do it just right.

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a data wipe and wipe the cache as well. I would then reinstall the CM7 package on the device.

If the issue is specifically with CWM crashing, it could be because the partitions are sizes that CWM doesn't support. I had an issue like that with my Nook Color. I have a nerwer model and the data partitions were 5GB and the media partition was 2GB, the older versions had it reversed. I found a script that someone already created to put the partitions back to the old format and CWM worked fine after that.

Now, I am taking a shot in the dark here on this, as I do not have that device, nor have I really read anything about it or the issue you are describing.